# What is the Best Test Automation Approach for WatiN

Tags: nunit, cruisecontrol.net, watin

I Studied both data-driven and keyword driven approaches. After reading, It seems data driven is better than keyword. For documentation purpose keyword sounds great. But it has many levels. I need guidance from people who actually have implemented Automation frameworks. Personally, I want to store all data in database or excel and break up the system into modular parts (functions that are common to major company products).

Currently using, WatiN, Nunit, CC.net

Any advise pls

Answer (score 1):

I would hightly recommend that you look into the stack that Michael Hunter aka the braidy tester built for testing expression at Microsoft he has a lot of articles about it http://www.thebraidytester.com/stack.html

Esentially he splits out into a logical model, a physical model and a data model and all three are loosley copupled. All my stacks are written this way now. So the test cases end up looking like this:

Logical.Google.Search.Websearch("watin");

Verification.VerifySearchResult("watin");

All the test data is then stored in a sql express database that indexed by the text string, in this case watin.

You will need to build a full domain model and data access layer, I personally auto generate that using SubSonic.